# I want to know delay function in c++

Tags: c++, delay

`usleep` does not ensure delay exactly in userspace because of cpu situation.

I want to know a function that ensures delay in userspace (c, c++) regardless of cpu situation.

Comment: Check if [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) helps you out in a way.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  *Why* do you need to delay for an exact time period?

Comment: It is probably operating system specific (and `usleep` is not, AFAIK, in *standard* C++11); so please **edit your question** to improve it (tell more about your implementation and operating system, and the actual application)

Comment: Don't sleep then?  Use an atomic variable?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are using a hard real-time operating system (in which case, see its documentation), you are *always* vulnerable to the scheduler deciding to kick you out and let another thread run.  `usleep` makes this more likely (because the scheduler thinks "he didn't want to run for 100µs, what difference can another µs make?"), but there is no way to make it go away altogether.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible while you call such a function from the user space. Your processus can be preempted and forced to wait for a time before waking up again. You should use a real-time sytem.